# OpenCL get_local_id Cost in Speed/Registers

Tags: opencl

In an OpenCL kernel, is it slower to call `get_local_id(0)` several times, instead of calling it once at the top - and later accessing that value from a local variable?

Do I use one fewer register by not storing `get_local_id(0)` to a local variable, and instead calling it several times?

Comment: If anything, your optimizer is most probably aware of all this anyway, given that he knows the value returned by `get_local_id` won't ever change in a single invocation. But a good start to check it might be to just look at the generated assembly (the NVidia compiler should be able to generate PTX from OpenCL C, and I guess AMD has similar features).

Comment: As far as I know, I doesn't change anything (as long as the optimization is on, which is by default).

Comment: Thanks guys!  I appreciate the advice so much.  I will check out the assembly.

Comment: Let us know what you find!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On most GPU architectures the local work item id will be held in a special set of registers that are set up by the hardware as it dispatches threads. This means that when you do a get_local_id(0) you are actually just reading from a register anyway, i.e. no speed loss 'calling' get_local_id(0).

The compiler *should* notice if you assign get_local_id(0) to a variable for subsequent use and generate the same code as if you'd get_local_id(0) every time. However, in my experience this is not always the case and you will notice exactly one register being saved by not using the variable to store the local id.

If you are tight for registers, I would suggest calling get_local_id(0) every time. You could even set up a macro to hide whether get_local_id(0) is being called or a register is being used. If you've got registers to spare (your profiler will tell you this) or prefer your code using a variable then go with a variable.